# Android Studio wizard not showing up

Tags: java, android-studio, window, archlinux

I've installed Android Studio on Arch linux with the `android-studio` AUR package, but when I run `android-studio` I get this:

[image]

It's just an empty window with a gray portion. How can I get it to open the wizard properly?

Answer (score 0):

Some Linux distributions doesn’t work well with some programs. Check parameters of your system for opening apps. But you can simply uninstall it and try it again. If the problem was not cleared try downloading another version of android studio. Check apps properties file if it’s not corrupted. If not helped ask Android studio devs. Or try updating you’re Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with my wm bspwm, when I changed the session for a desktop environment like kde, it works.